# Is there a way to iterate over CSS class names even if they are not used on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, sass

I am re-styling a webpage by changing its background color from black to white. There are a bunch of class names defined in the CSS file that represent text styles, but they are meant to be on a black background, so their colors will need to change for readability.

I could make a test page with a bunch of paragraphs like so:

```
<p class="text-style-1">ipsum lorem</p>
<p class="text-style-2">ipsum lorem</p>
<p class="text-style-3">ipsum lorem</p>
```

Then, at a glance, I could tell what styles need to be changed for readability.

This would work fine, but if miss one due to human error, I'll be relying on luck or customer feedback to discover my mistake. It'll also get out of sync if I add/remove text styles in the future.

So my question is, is there a way to iterate existing class names that start with `text-style-`, even when the page doesn't have any elements that use them?

I've tried googling for a solution, but the results are mainly tutorials on how to use `getElementsByClassName`, which in this case, does not apply: I don't have any elements on the page.

I am using SASS. Maybe it can provide some sort of solution that isn't possible with regular CSS. I've also considered writing a shell script to parse the CSS file with the text styles. This would work better than the proposed solution, but I'm hoping there's a solution limited to HTML, JS, CSS/SASS.

Comment: I'm confused: you want to "iterate existing class names..., even when the page doesn't have any elements that use them"; if they aren't on the page, where do these class names "exist"? is there an array somewhere with all possible class names meeting the condition?

Comment: @JackFleeting "where do these class names "exist"?" only in a CSS file.

Comment: Why not to load a different stylesheet when you switch to dark theme?

Comment: @MohamedBelhaj are you asking because it might help with my problem? This won't be customizable by the user. If it is in the future, I can grab the styles from my version control history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over `document.styleSheets` and check each rule.

For example:

```js
const allClasses = [];
for (const { cssRules } of document.styleSheets)
  for (const { selectorText } of cssRules) {
    for (const m of selectorText?.match(/\.text-style-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/g) || [])
      allClasses.push(m.slice(1));
  }
console.log(allClasses);
```

```css
.text-style-1{}
.text-style-2{}
.text-style-3{}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought you'd be interested in knowing that I asked chat gpt before submitting my question and it told me this can't be done. Good thing I never trust it.